# What kernel version is required for module development?

Tags: drivers

Is it necessary to have 2.6 kernel when referring to ldd3 modules for development?

If so, what would be the best resource for kernel module development on 4.15 kernel?

Comment: Kernel 2.6 is EoL for many years. So the question is unclear. You don't need this kernel for anything.

Comment: The current kernel is somehow considered 2.6 series since the massive architectural changes between 2.4 and 2.6, nowadays the latest kernel is 5.3-rc4 and the stable is 5.2.8, the ones available by default on stable Ubuntu are a bit older, I'm currently using Disco Dingo with 5.0.

Answer (score 2):

The current kernel is somehow considered 2.6 series since the massive architectural changes between 2.4 and 2.6.

Nowadays (August 2019) the latest kernel is 5.3-rc4 and the stable is 5.2.8, the ones available by default on stable Ubuntu are a bit older, I'm currently using Disco Dingo (19.04) with 5.0, while Eoan Ermine (19.10) already upgraded to 5.2 on the systems that I checked.